# Different AUC score from xgb and sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using xgboost's sklearn wrapper for a binary classifcation task and then use sklearn.metrics' auc for scoring

```
df = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.33)#, random_state=7)

params={
    'n_estimators':500,
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'learning_rate': 0.05,
    'gamma':0.1,
    'subsample':0.8,
    'colsample_bytree':0.3,
    'min_child_weight':3,
    'max_depth':6,
    'seed':1024,
    }

clf = XGBClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, \
        eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], \
                  eval_metric='auc', early_stopping_rounds = 50)
```

the output gives the result as :

```
[499]   validation_0-auc:0.991635       validation_1-auc:0.939632
```

but when I use auc scoring function by following code:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

the result is :

```
0.855832401454
```

anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Check the param ```average``` of roc_auc_score within sklearn. You can also search the issues on sklearn's github sources, as metric-diffs between sklearn and other libs are very popular (most of the time the users do not really understand the used metric). This is also unsurprising as there are many different definitions.

Comment: @sascha if I use xgb directly. the auc result matches the sklearn.metrics output

Answer (score 1):

Use the predicted score instead of classes in roc_auc_score() function.

```
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
print metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pred)
```